# why is there no wash profit in taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks

Say someone lost like $100k from trading in 1 year.  Now their investment is going up.  Should they sell $3000 worth of stocks then buy it back immediately to take advantage of the $100k loss every year if their original plan was to hold?

Is this a good strategy since there is no such thing as wash gains?

After reading some answers I think I misunderstood the $3000 as the max amount you can offset the capital gains per year from previous capital gains losses.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - it's called "tax gain harvesting" and it allows you to benefit from loss deductions now rather than having to carry them forward.

Why is there no law against it?

It's hard to say why a law does *not* exist, but here are a few possibilities:

- It's a much less common occurrence (having more than than $3k limit in losses *and* enough unrealized gains to offset them)
- Tax gain harvesting does not change your current tax bill - it just reduces the amount of gain that you'd report eventually, and reduces how much loss you can carry forward
- It's not a big enough problem that anyone had lobbied congress to make a law preventing it.

Comment: So is this a good strategy to sell buy back $3000 worth of stock of a long term investment every year for this case?

Comment: Yes, in principle. But depending on your specific tax situation and income future it _could_ be not.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a good strategy since there is no such thing as wash gains?

IMHO, this is not a very good strategy.

The $3000 is not a random magic number - it's the amount of capital loss that you can deduct from your **ordinary** income. In many cases, ordinary income is taxed at higher rates than capital gains, so tax-wise you'd be better off deducting the loss from ordinary income than performing gain harvesting.

However, if your losses are very high it may take many years to deduct all of them due to the $3000 limitation. In case of $100K loss it may take more than 33 years to write all of it off. In this case, your strategy would be to end up with as much *short term* capital gain as possible to use the offset, since again - you'll get higher tax benefit than writing off long term gain.

So if your accumulated losses are so high that you don't expect to deduct them from ordinary income in a reasonable (to you) amount of time - *then* you'll start with the gain losses strategy, preferring short term gains.

You don't have to limit the gains harvested to $3000, you can deduct all your capital gains from your capital losses, so if you have $100K gains all of a sudden - you can definitely harvest them all and get rid of the accumulated loss.

Comment: I see maybe I misunderstood the $3000 do tax software know to deduct the entire capital gains of this year from last year say 100k gain this year vs 100k loss last year?

Comment: @bakalolo I would expect them to, sure

Answer (score 1):

Why would you sell only $3,000 worth of stock with gains per year when you have a $100k loss from trading?  Is it a coincidence that the annual loss deduction is $3,000?  Or do you think that there's a limit on losses offset?

Be that as it may, if these gains are very short term, this tax gain harvesting makes sense.  You'd sell and repurchase, stepping up your cost basis.

Long term gains are taxed at a 15% rate.  If your tax harvesting positions have long term gains, you'll reset the long-term capital gains period of your holdings

If your $100k of losses are short term, they can be used to offset short-term gains which are taxed at a higher rate. Why waste the short-term loss deduction potential on long term gains that will be taxed at a lower rate?